# Did Al-Buraq really have wings?

Tags: reference-request, miraj

Everyone seems to somehow know this but I could not find a hadith in support of it.

Comment: If your post is about source-identification or reference-request it is more suitable to use these as tags, the hadith tag here seems a bit misleading! And please try to write well elaborated questions and show us your prior research effort, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t found any Ahaadeeth suggesting Buraq had wings.  I’m not an ‘aalim on the matter, but the only Hadeeth I’ve found involving “winged horses” was in Abi Dawud 4932 (graded Sahih by Albany), in which the Prophet (saws) was amused by such a notion:

...“He [Rasoolullaah (saws)] asked: What is this? She [‘Aaishah (ra)] replied: My dolls.
Among them he saw a horse with wings made of rags, and asked: What is this I see among them?
She replied: A horse. He asked: What is this that it has on it? She replied: Two wings. He asked: A horse with two wings? She replied: Have you not heard that Solomon had horses with wings? She said: Thereupon the Messenger of Allah (saws) laughed so heartily that I could see his molar teeth.

Answer (score 0):

According to [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/289763/), Buraq having wings is not mentioned in any authentic hadith.

> لم يثبت في حديث ، لا مرفوع ولا موقوف – فيما علمنا – أن البراق كان له جناحان ، وإنما ورد ذكر ذلك في بعض الأخبار التي لا يحتج بها لضعف أسانيدها
>
> It has not been proven in any hadith, neither marfoo’ nor mawqoof - as far as we know - that Al-Buraq had two wings. Rather, this was mentioned in some reports that cannot be used as evidence due to the weakness of their chains of narration.